# Read a CSV file with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file to my database with php. I have problems with the numbers so I try to import the file in an array with javascript. I notice that the numbers of the CSV are different when I import it. For example the number 23447 is "23    447"(including the space and quotes). How can my code edit the form of the number?

[image: js data]

[image: csv data]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
            if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var table = $("<table />");
                        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                            var row = $("<tr />");
                            var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                            if (cells.length > 1) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                                    var cell = $("<td />");
                                    cell.html(cells[j]);
                                    row.append(cell);
                                }
                                table.append(row);
                            }
                        }
                        $("#dvCSV").html('');
                        $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                    }
                    reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<hr />
<div id="dvCSV">
</div>
```

Comment: We can surely help you if you'd just provide us with your code and not just an image.

Comment: Which is the source data; the one with spaces or the one with commas?

Comment: I wrote my code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the spaces (whitespace characters are matched with the regex special character `\s`) then cast to a number. Apply this function to each csv cell value to process them:

```js
const processNumber = str => {
  const strWithoutSpaces = str.replace(/\s*/g, '');
  const numberFromStr = +strWithoutSpaces;
  return numberFromStr;
}

console.log(['10 000', '3 000 000', '100'].map(processNumber))
```